# Не срабатывает wp_head()

Tags: wordpress

Файл `functions.php` содержит в себе такой код:

```php
<?php 
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_styles' );

    function add_theme_styles() {
        echo "Themes added ";
    }
```

Файл `header.php` имеет в теге `head` такое содержимое:

```html
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Как видите очень простой код, но тем не менее на странице нигде не выводится текст *Themes added*, не могу понять в чем проблема, подскажите **почему не срабатывает действие `wp_head()` ?**

P.S. Так же после вызова `wp_head()` в теге `head` на странице появился отступ сверху, примерно 30px, значит ли это что `wp_head()` на самом деле сработал, а ошибка в файле `functions.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот хук для подключения стилей и скрпитов, а не вывода строки. Вы все выводите в Head документа, а не в тело документа.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_wp_head_css' ); // хук автоматом сработает во время wp_head
function my_wp_head_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_head_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/my_style.css', array(), null );
}
```

как еще вариант:

```
## CSS в head документа
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hook_css' );
function hook_css(){
    echo '<style>.wp_head_example{ background-color : #f1f1f1; } </style>';
}

## JS в head документа
add_action( 'wp_head','hook_javascript' );
function hook_javascript() {
    echo "<script> alert('Page is loading...'); </script>";
}
```